# send email with attachment in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, codeigniter-3, email-attachments

Pdf attachment through email in  CodeIgniter Mysource code here

```
  $this->load->library('email', $config);
  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
  $this->email->from('test@gmail.com'); 
  $this->email->to($useremail);
  $this->email->cc('');
  $this->email->subject('pdf');
  $this->email->message($message);
  $this->email->attach('public_html/invoicepdf/171.pdf');
  $mailsucc =   $this->email->send();
```

I tried with this but didnt work

```
$this->email->attach('public_html/invoicepdf/171.pdf');
```

And i also replace path with URL.

Comment: user FCPATH ,  $this->email->attach(FCPATH.'/path/to/photo1.jpg');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send attach file using

`$this->email->attach($atch);`

method in codeigniter. in this below code i'm sending mail using SMTP with
Attached File.

its Working perfectly.
 You only need to specify `base_url` to define attachment file path

**Controller**

```
$email_config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'yourmail@gmail.com', // change it to yours
    'smtp_pass' => 'mypasswords', // change it to yours
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);

// Defined Attachment file using variable
$atch=base_url().'html/images/logo.png';

$this->load->library('email', $email_config);

$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('test@gmail.com', 'Rudra');  // email From
$this->email->to('mailtosend@gmail.com');       // eMail to send
$this->email->subject('Mail with Attachment');  // Subject
$this->email->message("This is mail with Attachment file using CodeIgniter.");  // Message
$this->email->attach($atch);  // Attachment file defined using variable

$maill=$this->email->send(); // send mail

if($maill>0)
 {
  echo 'Email sent.';  // success
 }
 else
{
 show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

Comment: Hi Rudra i tried this code but am getting empty mail? when i removed this attachment code its working fine,i also checked my fle path.

Comment: Can you share your controller method with config file? I think you might be missed to configured it

Comment: how to share can i know your email id?

Comment: can you share your email id, i just want to show you  that code working Properly and you will get an Image  as attachment

Comment: just check your mail please and give feedback here